PHP PDO SQL Server - Timestamp data type issue
I am upgrading a PHP application from an older 5.4 version to the latest 8.3.8 using PDO SQLSrv to connect to my database.  I have a timestamp data type in the database to check if a record has been modified prior to the user submitting their version of the data (preventing concurrent updates).
The below code when run on 5.4 will correctly return a string similar to 00000000009FA279, however PHP 8.3.8 using the same settings returns a weird looking string A�.  Any help on resolving this is appreciated.
$db = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=MyServer;Database=MyDatabase", 'MyUser', 'MyPassword', array(PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_ENCODING => PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_SYSTEM));
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT [timestamp] FROM MyTable WHERE Id= 1');
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($row);

If I get the metadata for the column, PDO correctly says it is a timestamp
Array
(
    [flags] => 0
    [sqlsrv:decl_type] => timestamp
    [native_type] => string
    [table] => 
    [pdo_type] => 2
    [name] => timestamp
    [len] => 8
    [precision] => 0
)

For clarification, I am looking specifically at the SQL timestamp data type and not a date/time timestamp.

For anyone getting to this page having a similar issue that I did, the answer turned out to be that the old functionality I was seeing in the 5.4 version of pdo_sqlsrv was considered a bug.  See Issue 553, Issue 270, and PR 297 on the MS PHP SQL GitHub page.
New versions of the PDO driver interpret the timestamp data type as binary instead of hex.  To correct this, use bin2hex to convert the binary data into a valid hex string.
